# How to pass disable warning flag via Xcode to "swift-frontend" command when invoking to generate swift bridging header

Tags: swift

I have a project that wants to set treat warning as error, however, currently there is one last warning issues need to be addressed before switching.

It's generating swift bridging header process, it's invoked by swift-frontend, and when compiling the header, the 3rd party lib React-Native is having 36 same warnings related to nulliable annotation check on its files, I noticed the latest code on their side still has such, so how to surpass them from my project side, I tried lots of approaches, but no luck